# Error on docker-ce installation on Debian

Tags: debian, apt, docker

I am having a problem installing docker on my server:

```
    user@server:/# apt-get install docker-ce
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      docker-ce
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 0 B/30.2 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 152 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
    debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76, <> line 1.)
    debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
    Selecting previously unselected package docker-ce.
    (Reading database ... 25607 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../docker-ce_17.12.0~ce-0~debian_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking docker-ce (17.12.0~ce-0~debian) ...
    Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u7) ...
    Setting up docker-ce (17.12.0~ce-0~debian) ...
    Job for docker.service failed. See 'systemctl status docker.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
    invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
    dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u7) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     docker-ce
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
    user@server:/# journalctl -xn
    -- Logs begin at Thu 2018-02-15 11:45:24 CET, end at Thu 2018-02-15 12:05:46 CET. --
    Feb 15 12:05:46 git systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
    Feb 15 12:05:46 git systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
    Feb 15 12:05:46 git systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
    -- Subject: Unit docker.service has begun shutting down
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    --
    -- Unit docker.service has begun shutting down.
    Feb 15 12:05:46 git systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Socket for the API.
    -- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    --
    -- Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down.
    Feb 15 12:05:46 git systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
    -- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun with start-up
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    --
    -- Unit docker.socket has begun starting up.
    Feb 15 12:05:46 git systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
    -- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished start-up
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    --
    -- Unit docker.socket has finished starting up.
    --
    -- The start-up result is done.
    Feb 15 12:05:46 git systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
    -- Subject: Unit docker.service has begun with start-up
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    --
    -- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
    Feb 15 12:05:46 git systemd[1]: docker.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
    Feb 15 12:05:46 git systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
    -- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    --
    -- Unit docker.service has failed.
    --
    -- The result is failed.
    Feb 15 12:05:46 git systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
```

SysInfo:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
```

Kernel:

```
2.6.32-042stab127.2
```

Comment: I am on a hosted vserver i guess the error relates to some virtualization limitations... might this be possible?

Comment: Seems like it :( if u feel like posting that as an answer i will accept it. Thanks for your help and time anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Docker's installation documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/#install-daemon-and-client-binaries-on-linux) the minimum kernel required is 3.10 and you're running a 2.6.32-042stab127.2 with Debian 8 which usually runs 3.16.

It appears to be an OpenVZ kernel. From its [main page](https://openvz.org/Main_Page) it's already a container-based virtualization. So that would mean running a container in a container. While that's possible, there are limitations, especially for an application like Docker that is made to run and control containers.

Those are two reasons that make the environment unacceptable to run Docker. You should try with a provider using more common virtualization. If you can choose your kernel (even among a provided list) or change it, that should be a suitable choice. Of course bare metal is always a suitable choice too.